# SSH from WSL to a VM running on the host fails

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ssh, virtualbox

I am running WSL 2 on Windows from which I am running vagrant.

Vagrant provisions a Centos 7.6 VM in VirtualBox running on the host.

The VM listens to port 22 for SSH and Virtualbox maps the port 22 of the VM to

The VM provisioning works just fine.

But when I try to SSH from WSL to the VM, it does not work.
I tried using 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 and the IP of the host machine.

I can ssh just fine when I try from the powershell on the host. What gives?

I have created rules in the firewall allowing traffic on 2222

I am using Windows 10 with WSL 2, with ubuntu 18.04 for the WSL.

Comment: I had similar issue, however first time actually worked - I made a clean setup with vagrant init and then vagrant up and then vagrant ssh.
However it has somehow stopped working - no warnings or errors - in fact I can make a vagrant up ( a machine is created in my windows VirtualBox ) but I never managed to connect to it with the ssh.

I guess some sort of setup with vagrant and ssh is failing, however I unfortunately do not yet know where

Comment: however I suspect that it could have something to do with firewall settings !?